# access to database remotely-NESTED EXCEPTION

Tags: java, database, ssh, remote-access

I want to make a connection to the remote database ssh, in my java program, so I write a java code for this, I can ssh to the database server from my code but I can't access to the database, this is my out put which contains the error :
(this link is my previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646166/where-i-should-put-jar-file-in-connection-to-remote-database-ssh-java-lang-c) ,which is related to this question)

```
hi
identity added
session created.
session connected.....
shell channel connected....
connecting to database ...
db Method...
try-catch
Connecting to database...
DB_URL : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3366/DBNAME
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.io.EOFException
MESSAGE: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1997)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:573)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1044)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2748)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at Main.connectToDB(Main.java:78)
        at Main.main(Main.java:49)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.io.EOFException
MESSAGE: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1997)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:573)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1044)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2748)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at Main.connectToDB(Main.java:78)
        at Main.main(Main.java:49)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:641)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1044)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2748)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at Main.connectToDB(Main.java:78)
        at Main.main(Main.java:49)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2820)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at Main.connectToDB(Main.java:78)
        at Main.main(Main.java:49)
Goodbye!
done
```

I run this code

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        try {
                System.out.println("hi");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            String user = "***";
            String host = "**.**.***.***";
            int port = 22;
            String privateKey = "id_rs";

            jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
            System.out.println("identity added ");

            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            System.out.println("session created.");

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);

            session.connect();
           session.setPortForwardingL( 3366, host, 3306)  ;

            System.out.println("session connected.....");

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
            channel.connect();
            System.out.println("shell channel connected....");
            System.err.println("connecting to database ...");

           connectToDB();

          System.out.println("done");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }


        static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        static String databaseName ="DBNAME";
       static  int lport = 3366;
        static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+lport+"/"+databaseName;

        static final String USER = "***";
        static final String PASS = "***";

  public static void connectToDB() {
                System.out.println("db Method...");
                Connection conn = null;
                Statement stmt = null;
                try{
                        System.out.println("try-catch");
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
                        System.err.println("DB_URL : "+DB_URL);
                        System.err.println(USER+":"+PASS+";");
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

                        System.out.println("hey!");
                        stmt = conn.createStatement();
                        String sql;
                        sql="SELECT * from Customer_Classes ; ";
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                       try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("a.txt"))) {
                                while(rs.next()){
                                      String name = rs.getString("ID");
                                      bw.write(name);
                                      bw.newLine();

                                      System.out.println(" name: " + name);
                                }
                                bw.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        rs.close();
                        stmt.close();
                        conn.close();
                }catch(SQLException se){
                        se.printStackTrace();
                }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                        try{
                                if(stmt!=null)
                                        stmt.close();
                        }catch(SQLException se2){
                            System.err.println("unable to close statement");
                        }
   }
                        try{
                                if(conn!=null)
                                        conn.close();
                        }catch(SQLException se){
                               System.err.println("unable to close connection");
                               se.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
}
```

I define a user in remote server with all privilages

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';`

and add my Ip to bind-address in my.cnf (in DBserver)

what this errors means? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. When connecting through portforwarding, the database will not see your original IP address, but the local one (localhost). So your grant should be `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';`
2. Mysql's *bind-address* parameter is for configuring the **server** IP, not the **client** IP. You should leave that setting (unless you otherwise need it) at its default, since you will be connecting from localhost anyway.
3. If `Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");`does what it seems to (i.e. connect you to the SFTP subsystem), sshd will probably not let you connect elsewhere. You should use `Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");`
4. Check the server log.

Comment: thanks :) ,  I grant new privileges for my user with this syntax . and change the openChannel too ,but I get very exception. about part 2: i don't understand ,I wrote bind-address in database server, you mean I should write it in the code server( the server which want to access remotely to db) ? , I check the secure and message log in /var/log/ , but can't find any thing related.

Comment: You wrote "I ...  add my Ip to bind-address in my.cnf (in DBserver)". The DB server does not see your client's IP address at all. So you must not configure it anywhere on the DB server side, and nowhere in any my.cnf. bind-address tells the DB server on what IP to listen. `session.setPortForwardingL( 3366, host, 3306)` forwards all traffic to port 3306 on the address "host", so your DB server should bind to that address. If you use `session.setPortForwardingL( 3366, "localhost", 3306)`, then your DB server must listen on localhost (bind-address: 127.0.0.1)

Comment: I can't understand :( , I change the setportforwadringL second element to 127.0.0.1 , but doesn't work.